# How to debug a single robolectric unit test in Android Studio

Tags: android, debugging, gradle, android-studio, robolectric

I am able to debug my android gradle project if I run all the unit tests using the following steps:

First configure IDE With a Gradle Run/Debug config for Unit Testing Using Robolectric & JUnit

1. in IDE menu do: File / Settings / Compiler / Gradle : Uncheck "Use in-process build"
2. In IDE do: Run / Edit Configuration / + / Gradle
3. Enter the following data in fields: Name: test , Gradle project: .../app/build.gradle, Tasks: test, Script parameters: --debug --stacktrace

Next, to run / debug tests from IDE do:

1. Choose "test" from configuration
2. To Run: Run / Run 'test'
3. To Debug: Run / Debug 'test'

This allows me to run all the tests in the debugger.

I am now looking to find a way to do the same but for a single specified test only. Any suggestions how would be great.

Comment: you doing all the steps to debug a test in android studio? Which plugin  use you? Some plugins give you full robolectric support at android studio like https://github.com/JCAndKSolutions/android-unit-test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the version of gradle you are using.  If you are using version 1.x, then add the following script parameter to your run configuration

```
-Dtest.single=<testfilename>
```

e.g.

```
-Dtest.single=MyTest
```

You don't have to worry about the path to the file - just the name of the file containing the test class without the trailing `.java`

If you are using gradle 2.x, then add the following script parameter to your run configuration

```
--tests <test class name>
```

e.g.

```
--tests com.example.data.MyTest
```

or
    --tests *.MyTest

With wildcards you can run not just one test but a subset of your tests

```
--tests com.example.data.*
```

Comment: I am using gradle 1.12 and -Dtest.single=MyTest (with MyTest replaced with an impl specific test class without package qualification) did not work. All test were run instead. I tried specifying as both VM option and script parameters and neither helped.

Comment: The portion of above answer that relates to gradle 2.x worked for me. The portion that relates to gradle 1.x did not.